# Mixing bootstrap and google material for Angular projects

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am using Material and Flex and eg `@angular/material` and `@angular/flex-layout`

I am using flex for layouts that are reactive.

I am looking for an elegant way todo simple things like margins.

I know I could just add some CSS, but then it need to be reactive, maybe I don't want the margin on smaller screens etc, again I could just do this with CSS but the more CSS I less value I am getting from the framework.

I have found that using bootstrap for this works well, but I have also read that mixing bootstrap and material is not a good idea.

This is my code

```
<div class="m-md-2">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="10px grid">
        <div fxFlex="25"  fxFlex.sm="33.3" fxFlex.xs="50" *ngFor="let dashboardAppPart of dashboardAppParts">
             ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Are they are problems with mixing up bootstrap with material / flex or can this be done with pure flex?

Comment: so basically, you want to use the grid from bootstrap? Maybe it would be too big code bloat using bootstrap just for few features you can do with help of flex and some custom css if needed. Not to mention time aspect, how much will it take to eliminate and solve all conflicts between bootstrap and material, vs. to do the custom approach.

Comment: @niklaz If I can do it all with flex, that would be fine. Its the reactive margins that I am finding useful from bootstrap.

Comment: Nope. bootsrap and material flex layout are not working together.
but basically you can use flex for anything you try to accomplish with bootsrap

Comment: So, I need to read up more on flex? I am struggling to get a the boarder that `m-md-2` gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally You should try to avoid using both at the same time, but if in any case you really need to use bootstrap with Material, you can only import certains aspect which you actually want to use e.g. typography or grid system instead of importing complete bootstrap styles.

Also you should avoid importing bootstrap.js (which is responsible for handling working of bootstrap modals and drop downs) or JQuery since both directly manipulates DOM which can be considered more like an anti pattern for Angular instead of optimized DOM manipulations.

You can also have a look at some of the bootstrap rewrites for angular, there are a few good ones, e.g. [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Now coming at the specific shared scenario, this can be achieved with out using bootstrap, because flex layout already exposes specialized `ngClass` and `ngStyle` directives which are great for handling reactive layouts. Following is an example of how this can be achieved,

> ngClass.xs="list-custom"

and here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-ngclass?embed=1&file=src/app/list-sections-example.html) showing this behavior in action,

```
<mat-list ngClass.xs="list-custom">
    <h3 mat-subheader>Notes</h3>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let note of notes">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>note</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line fxFlex="100">{{note.name}}</h4>
        <p mat-line fxFlex="100"> {{note.updated | date}} </p>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

and here it is in action,

[image]

In my example `.list-custom` is only adding a bit of margin and background, but you can use these reactive directives to achieve what ever you intend to, the best thing about this is that you don't have to write custom media queries. Also I hope you are aware you can introduce custom break points as well in flex layout; e.g. say `xxxl` for special handling a certain resolution, you can even combine these custom break points with these reactive directives like this `ngClass.xxxl` and `ngStyle.xxxl`.

do read the [docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API) to flex-layout `ngClass` directive and for other supported directives [check this out](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview#api-for-any-element).

Comment: That is working for me, I guess I thought they might be a pure flex grid option.